# How do you update Meteor on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, meteor

I have Meteor PREVIEW 0.5.7 running on windows 8 and this is what happened :

> //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> meteor is out of date. Please run:
>
> ```
>      meteor update
> ```
>
> //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> Updating through Meteor is not yet supported on Windows. Check out http://win.me
>
> teor.com weekly...

And I did check win.meteor.com out but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows version of meteor is currently under development, so updating over 0.5.7 version on Windows is not possible at this time.